# regex for extracting text after a word and before a special character and to exclude all other numeric

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex which for a given example text

```
Section 2.1. 1.1.14. Minimum Rent Schedule (subiect to adjustment, if applicable):less than or greater than twelve (12) full calendar months (and such proration or adjustment being based upon the actual number of days in such Lease Year)
```

Output desired

```
Minimum Rent Schedule (subiect to adjustment, if applicable)
```

Everything between the word `'Section'` and upuntill special character `':'`. But like in here,  I don't want it to capture anything with numbers.

What I have tried until now is

```
[Section]+.*[:]
```

Comment: Does your requirement possibly include a larger text, and, if so, can you include sample data for that?

Answer (score 1):

This is one pattern.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "Section 2.1. 1.1.14. Minimum Rent Schedule (subiect to adjustment, if applicable):less than or greater than twelve (12) full calendar months (and such proration or adjustment being based upon the actual number of days in such Lease Year)"
print(re.match(r"Section[\d.\s]+(.*?):", s).group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
Minimum Rent Schedule (subiect to adjustment, if applicable)
```

---

If you have multiple elements use `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
print(re.findall(r"Section[\d.\s]+(.*?):", your_text))
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you tried uses a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match any of the listed characters 1+ times.

To not match anything which contains numbers after `Section`, you could repeat 0+ times matching a space followed by non whitespace characters that contain at least a single number.

Capture what follows that does not contain a number in a group.

```
Section (?:[^\s\d]*\d\S* )*([^:]+):
```

**Explanation**

- `Section`  Match Section and space
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^\s\d]*` Match any char except a whitespace char and a digit 0+ times using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
  - `\d\S*`  Then match a digit followed by matching 0+ times a non whitespace char
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `([^:]+):` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ times any char except a `:`, then match a `:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nwZcKq/1)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"Section (?:[^\s\d]*\d\S* )*([^:]+):"
s = "Section 2.1. 1.1.14. Minimum Rent Schedule (subiect to adjustment, if applicable):less than or greater than twelve (12) full calendar months (and such proration or adjustment being based upon the actual number of days in such Lease Year)"
print(re.match(regex, s).group(1))
```

Result

> Minimum Rent Schedule (subiect to adjustment, if applicable)

To find multiple, you could use re.findall:

```
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

[Demo using re.findall](https://ideone.com/UZMexQ)